# What happens under the hood in any C++ compiler with reference variables?

Tags: c++

When we declare a reference variables `int & x = something`, is the `&` just a syntactical shorthand in the source code for referencing the value of the variable `something`? What I mean is, does the compiler insert, under the hood, the necessary calls for pointers in order to access the value of `something`, or does it use some more direct approach? E.g. do we have that `int x & = something` is equal to `int*  x = &something`, and using the value at `x` like `x = 10` results in the code `*x = 10`?

Comment: It depends on the exact case.  The C++ standard says a reference does not require any storage so it can just be an alias to the referred to object and it is that object that is accessed directly.  Only way to know for sure is to check the assembly.

Comment: you are mixing what a reference is, how it is specified ("is the & just a syntactical shorthand in the source code for referencing the value of the variable something"-yes kind of) and how that is implemented by compilers. Thats two different questions. References arent pointers, but the implementation of references typically does use pointers

Comment: Best to think of a reference as an alias for an object.  Like how a `typedef` is an alias for a type.